# How do I configure my ssh-server, so that it can use the same user name to log in to different users, as github do?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

We can use `git@github.com` and just provision the `'git'` as the login name for github at work.

How do I configure my ssh-server, so that it can use the same user name to log in to different users, just like github.

Sorry for my poor english ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add their public-keys to the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You might want to add some restrictions on what they are allowed to, or not (actually logging into the server, etc).

Comment: thx for reply, but i think there are two options `command="command" ` and `environment="NAME=value"` in the authorized_keys can be useful for me, they can do this perfectly.